# Decrypt with Public Key in C/C++

Tags: c++, encryption, openssl, poco-libraries

So I'm currently working on a web service for Amazon Alexa. 
For their request authentication, I'm downloading and validating a certificate. Afterwards I shall decrypt a signature with the certificate's public key.
Now I've tried some things with Poco and OpenSSL, never getting a fitting result.

One example as a try for OpenSSL:

```
void decryptWithPublicKey(const std::string & input, const std::shared_ptr<Poco::Crypto::X509Certificate> & cert, std::string & buffer)
{
     RSA * decryptor = Poco::Crypto::RSAKey(*key).impl()->getRSA();
     const unsigned char * from = (const unsigned char*) input.c_str();
     unsigned char* to = new unsigned char[ RSA_size(decryptor)-12 ];;

     int result = RSA_public_decrypt((int) input.length(), from, to, decryptor, RSA_PKCS1_PADDING);
     if(result == -1)
     {
         // print error
     }
     else
     {
         buffer.append((char*) to);
     }

     delete from;
     delete[] to;
}
```

Output is always sth like "0!0     +\n PuTTYPuTTY"

Anyone has any experience with that?

Comment: The language either *is* or *isn't* C. This isn't.

Comment: *"Decrypt with Public Key"* is not a valid cryptographic operation. Maybe you want a *Probabilistic Signature Scheme with Recovery (PSSR)* instead?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala - It appears to be both. OpenSSL is a C library, and he is using it in C++. C++ was intended to be a superset of C, but they have slightly differing behaviors in a few areas that could be affecting the problem. [Unions and inactive member access](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11373203/608639) comes to mind for me because it bit me a few times.

Comment: @jww that's why I tagged both. And Yes, I know, but I haven't read about PSSR, yet. Do you know any C/C++ implementation of said scheme?

Comment: @be_bri - *"Do you know any C/C++ implementation of [PSSR]"* - Jack Lloyd's [Botan](https://botan.randombit.net/) or Wei Dai's [Crypto++](https://www.cryptopp.com/).